# Need to change gsuite users signature in gmail

Tags: python, gmail-api

I have researched two weeks and can't find any information how I can change user's signature in gmail via python script. Do you have any solution of this issue?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.   When asking a question it is best to post the code you are currently using as well as any issues you are having with that code.   In the event that you have done some research links to the research you have done can also be helpful.  The statement **I cant find any information** is highly unlikly due to the fact that there are billions of pages in Google you must have found something even something that did not help

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail Settings API has methods that allow management of the users signature you can find information about them here [Manage signature](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings)

You should be aware that this API is deprecated is deprecated and will be turned down on October 16, 2019. Migrate to the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings) as soon as possible to avoid disruptions to your application.

**Gmail API**

[Manag signature settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_signature_settings) states that you should use To manage email signatures in the Gmail API, use the [SendAs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs) resource.  Which will let you set a signature.

**Python**

I suggest you follow the [python quick start](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and the try and edit it for use with the sendAs method

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```